# Intellij doesn't show "Assigned but not used private fields" warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea

have this class

```
public class Foo {
    private final String text;

    public Foo(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("replace this string with the text variable");
    }
}
```

the `text` field is assigned but not used. Is there an intellij setting that can warn this?

Comment: Look in the settings under "Inspections" and search for "unused".

Comment: I checked all unused field under java. this field is not greyed out.

Comment: Inspections will never be greyed out, afaik. But you can set the inspection level (don't show, suggestion, weak warning, warning, error)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the *Java | Declaration redundancy | Unused declaration* inspection, that should trigger the warning in your case.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks. I think I asked the wrong question, it is above lombok's @RequiredArgsConstructor mess with this check.